# Linux kernel module ABI (x86)

Tags: linux, x86, kernel, abi

I'm looking for an official definition of the ABI used for calls in kernel modules on x86. I recently looked into a compiled module and was surprised to discover that:

- it uses registers to pass the first three arguments (`eax`, `edx` and
  `ecx`).
- it's not `fastcall` as described in GCC docs. The [docs say](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) that
  `fastcall` uses ecx and edx (Microsoft style).

The only somewhat relevant info I could find was [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/kvm-devel/msg09495.html), but it's not saying much at all.

So:

1) Is there any official documentation on the ABI used in kernel modules (not the syscall ABI and not just the function list - those I did find).

2) How is this weird fastcall produced by the compiler? Is there a switch I missed?

Comment: it is actually `__fastcall`, but not the MS variant, rather the Borland version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Borland_fastcall

Comment: Note that on 32-bit x86 systems, another convention is used for the functions with variable argument lists, these get all their arguments on stack. x86-64 is another story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-mregparm=3` is responsible for this.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! Now that I know the keyword I found [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/66965/) which is probably the origin of the whole thing. Still, would be nice to have this somewhere in the docs as well...